# How to bootstrap one tailed test for two proportions?

Tags: bootstrap, proportion, one-tailed-test

Let's say we have two proportions. p1: 70 successes in 700 trials; and p2: 48 successes in 300 trial. I know how to bootstrap two sided test, where null hypothesis is p1 = p2 and alternative is p1 != p2. In this case I can model null hypothesis by pooling these proportions together into one proportion with 70 + 48 = 118 successes in 700 + 300 = 1000 trials, then generating samples from it and calculating % of times when absolute difference between means is greater of equal to original difference 48/300 - 70/700 = 0.06.

I don't understand how to model null hypothesis for one tailed test, where it should be either p1 - p2 >= 0 or p1 - p2 <= 0. And alternatives are p1 - p2 < 0 and p1 - p2 > 0. How can I perform these one tailed test using bootstrap?

Comment: Why not do exactly the same thing up to the final step, wherein you calculate the % of times when your sample p1 > your sample p2?

Comment: @jbowman If I do it like that then null hypothesis will be incorrect: two tails h0: p1 = p2; one tail p1 >= p2 or p2 <= p1. If I do it this way I will get equal p-values for both one tailed tests (p1>p2 and p1<p2), but p-values should be different: one p-value should be high, and other should be low.

Comment: If you are calculating the fraction of times p1 > p2 and using that as your p-value, how is that going to give you the same p-value as if you calculate the fraction of times p1 < p2 and use *that* as your p-value?  If 85% of the bootstrap samples have p1 > p2, doesn't it stand to reason that <= 15% of the samples will have p1 < p2?

Comment: @jbowman I got it, thank you! I tried it and got correct results. But in this case we use different null hypothesis: instead of p1 >= p2 or p1 <= p2 we use p1 = p2. Anyway, your idea works. Thank you a lot!